# Using AJAX in a Shared MVC Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I have AJAX working for a single page, but I want it to work across all pages. How can I accomplish it?

Here is the JavaScript in scripts.cshtml:

```
function changeTab(tabId) {
    var url = "Home/changeTab/" + tabId;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/changeTab/" + tabId,
        success: function (tab) {
            var t = tab;
            $("#menu1").html(t);
        }
    });
}
```

I have a component Home.cs:

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public JsonResult changeTab(int id)
    {
        var saveTab = id;
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        [...]
        return Json(username, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
}
```

The code works well on the Home page, but not on any other. Where do I place the changeTab function so that every page can call it?

Comment: Might you mean `url: "/changeTab/" + tabId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your script into the following :

```
function changeTab(tabId) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("changeTab", "Home")/' + tabId;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (tab) {
            var t = tab;
            $("#menu1").html(t);
        }
    });
}
```